# Magento 2: don't show "saved price" in attribute selection

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

when a product has a special price, I see the "saved price" (e.g. -$7.34) in the attribute selection, for example:

### [image: Attribute slector]

How can I remove it and just show the value of the attribute?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean on product details page on frontend?

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes correct, on product detail page on frontend